# Python: What is Best Approach for Flattening a list of Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I flatten a List of dictionary with nested dictonaries, say I have the following dict:

```
data = [
            { 'Name':'xyx',
            'Age':22,
            'EmpDetails':{'Salary':100,'Job':'Intern','Location':'TER'}
            },
            { 'Name':'abc',
                'Age':23,
                'EmpDetails':{'JoinDate':'20110912','Salary':200,'Job':'Intern2','Location':'TER2'}
            },
            {'Name':'efg',
                'Age':24,
                'EmpDetails':{'JoinDate':'20110912','enddate':'20120912','Salary':300,'Job':'Intern3','Location':'TER3'}
            }
       ]
```

i would need the EmpDetails Node removed and move its values one level up, like below

```
data = [
            { 'Name':'xyx','Age':22,'Salary':100,'Job':'Intern','Location':'TER'},
            { 'Name':'abc','Age':23,'JoinDate':'20110912','Salary':200,'Job':'Intern2','Location':'TER2'},
            {'Name':'efg','Age':24,'JoinDate':'20110912','enddate':'20120912','Salary':300,'Job':'Intern3','Location':'TER3'}
       ]
```

i am this now using below, is there any faster way of doing this?

```
newlist = []
for d in data:
    empdict ={}
    for key, val in d.items():
        if(key!='EmpDetails'):
            empdict[key] = val
        if(key=='EmpDetails'):
            for key2, val2 in val.items():
                empdict[key2] = val2
    newlist.append(empdict)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one approach using `dict.update` and `.pop`

**Ex:**

```
data = [
            { 'Name':'xyx',
            'Age':22,
            'EmpDetails':{'Salary':100,'Job':'Intern','Location':'TER'}
            },
            { 'Name':'abc',
                'Age':23,
                'EmpDetails':{'JoinDate':'20110912','Salary':200,'Job':'Intern2','Location':'TER2'}
            },
            {'Name':'efg',
                'Age':24,
                'EmpDetails':{'JoinDate':'20110912','enddate':'20120912','Salary':300,'Job':'Intern3','Location':'TER3'}
            }
       ]

for i in data:
    i.update(i.pop("EmpDetails"))
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Age': 22, 'Job': 'Intern', 'Location': 'TER', 'Name': 'xyx', 'Salary': 100},
 {'Age': 23,
  'Job': 'Intern2',
  'JoinDate': '20110912',
  'Location': 'TER2',
  'Name': 'abc',
  'Salary': 200},
 {'Age': 24,
  'Job': 'Intern3',
  'JoinDate': '20110912',
  'Location': 'TER3',
  'Name': 'efg',
  'Salary': 300,
  'enddate': '20120912'}]
```

Comment: Very elegant answer. Is there a way to do this in a list comprehension (say, if I need to do this as part of another command and don't want an explicit for loop)? I know that `.update` won't do the trick because it changes in-place and does not return another dict

Comment: @ItamarMushkin Maybe you want see my answer, one line comprehension method.

Answer (score 3):

One line method, maybe a little tricky.

```py
data = [
    {
        "Name": "xyx",
        "Age": 22,
        "EmpDetails": {"Salary": 100, "Job": "Intern", "Location": "TER"},
    },
    {
        "Name": "abc",
        "Age": 23,
        "EmpDetails": {
            "JoinDate": "20110912",
            "Salary": 200,
            "Job": "Intern2",
            "Location": "TER2",
        },
    },
    {
        "Name": "efg",
        "Age": 24,
        "EmpDetails": {
            "JoinDate": "20110912",
            "enddate": "20120912",
            "Salary": 300,
            "Job": "Intern3",
            "Location": "TER3",
        },
    },
]

# only python3.5+
res = [{**item.pop("EmpDetails", {}), **item} for item in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer using `json_normalize()` method from pandas library since it would be an elegant solution and had no effect on readability of your code.

Examples can bee seen here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html

Comment: I tried using the json_normalize() method, the only problem i have with it is, it generates  a prefix. ex:EmpDetails.Salary. I tried setting record_prefix as None. like this json_normalize(Data,record_prefix=None). But it didn't work. Is there anyway i can get the same result without the prefix in the column name?

Comment: I can still achieve this by doing - op.columns = op.columns.str.replace('EmpDetails.', ''). But is there a default way of doing this?

Comment: Not sure if this would work but try setting _record_prefix_ to **False**. There is also another argument called _meta_prefix_, you may set this **False** also.